# Pandas grouping of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data shown below:

```
     Gender    topic: Big data infrastructure
    0     F     NaN
    1     M     -1
    2     M     -1
    3     M     -1
    4     F     1
    5     M     NaN
    6     M     NaN
    7     M     NaN
    8     M     -2
    9     M     1
    10    F     1
    11    M     NaN
    12    M     1
    13    M     -1
    14    M     1
    15    M     NaN
    16    M     NaN
    17    M     NaN
    18    M     -1
    19    M     -2
    20    F     1
    21    M     NaN
    22    M     NaN
    23    F     2
    24    M     -2
    25    F     2
    26    M     NaN
    27    M     2
    28    M     1
    29    M     NaN
    30    M     2
    31    M     NaN
    32    M     NaN
    33    F     2
    34    M     2
```

I want to somehow get a count of how many males and females gave a score of -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 or did not answer, but I cannot figure it out. I have tried a couple of groupby methods but they do not work. Does anyone have some guidance or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` and use `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('Gender')['topic: Big data infrastructure'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

The resulting output:

```
Gender  topic: Big data infrastructure
F        1.0                               3
         2.0                               3
        NaN                                1
M       NaN                               13
        -1.0                               5
         1.0                               4
        -2.0                               3
         2.0                               3
```

Comment: Thanks! How could access the counts? For example if I wanted to graph how many females and males gave the score of 1? @root

Comment: You currently have a Series with the two original columns as a MultiIndex, so you'd use the standard MultiIndex indexing, e.g. `df[:, 1]`.  Alternatively, you can revert back to having everything as columns by adding a `.rename('Count').reset_index()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: is there a way to split the columns so I have one column for the topic and then I have a column with the count for females and then a columns for the count with males

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can add `.unstack(level='Gender').fillna(0).reset_index()` after doing the `value_counts`.  If having your column axis named bothers you, you can add `.rename_axis(None, 1)` after resetting the index.

Comment: You are so awesome! I think this will work! I am trying to plot the result on a double bar graph and was having trouble!